# C++ Build 32bit binary on 64bit system

Tags: c++, 32bit

So I have a project that I want to be able to build as a 64bit binary as well as as a 32bit one.
My machine itself is 64bit and the 64bit compile works just fine.

I am using `cake` to build my project and I used the `set_target_properties(clib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")` to force a 32bit build.

Whenever I try to build this the compiler throws an error, because I am including `<iostream>` in my main program. At first it complained that it couldn't find `<bits/c++config.h>` which gets included somewhere inside `<iostream>`.
I found a couple of things online which led me to install `g++-multilib` on my system. Now the previous error is gone but instead I am getting the error
`/usr/include/linux/errno.h:1:10: fatal error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory` which also has its origins in the `#include <iostream>`.

I checked where this file is and I found it in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/errno.h` but (as before with the `c++config.h` the `x86_64` folder appears to not be searched in a 32bit build (which kinda makes sense).
I also found it in `/usr/include/linux/errno.h` which is identical to the precious one, but as you can see it is not in the `asm` subfolder.
Obviously I could manually move it into that folder but I have the feeling that there is something generally wrong with my setup here.

So what else do I have to setup in order for me being able to compile my code (with a `#include <iostream>`) as a 32bit executable? Is there something like a 32bit-version of the std-library?

EDIT:
I am using Linux Mint 18.3 with `g++ --version` of `g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0` and `cmake v.3.10.2`

Comment: This *should* “just work” with `g++-multilib` and its dependencies (and obviously it doesn’t, I’m not questioning that). What distribution (including its version) are you using?

Comment: @StephenKitt I added the information in the question - did I miss something?

Comment: Does it work if you build the problematic C++ file manually, without `cmake`? (This will help determine whether `g++` is causing problems, or `cmake`.)

Comment: @StephenKitt I just tried compiling it via `g++ -m32 main.cpp` but it resulted in the same error

Comment: Okay nvm- I found the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I found out what was the problem:
When I found out, I had to use `g++-multilib` I went ahead and searched for that in my package manager (`synaptic` in my case). That one listed a bunch of versions so I checked what version of `g++` I had installed and then I installed the appropriate `g++-multilib`-package which in my case was the `g++-7-multilib`.

However what it didn't install was the `gcc-multilib` package which appears to be the troublemaker in my case. After having installed that one, it worked as expected.

---

Long story short: If I had installed the `g++-multilib` (without a version in the name) package to begin with, I wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: Hah, good one; given your question it would have been difficult to find the answer for you (since you say you installed `g++-multilib`).

Comment: Yeah well - I _thought_ I did xD

Comment: Indeed; I’m just glad you found the answer on your own ;-).